# Mostrar array de una consulta ajax en una tabla javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy trayendo una consulta a la base de datos con ajax en un javascript, el resultado se captura en un array, como puedo mostrar ese array en una tabla.

Quiero mostrar lo que viene en la variable respuesta en una tabla ya que asi solo me muestra el primer valor encontrado

```
$(".tablasInformes").on("click", ".btnVerCoti", function() {
    var idCliente = $(this).attr("idCliente");
    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("idCliente", idCliente);
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/cliente-ventas.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta) {
            console.log(respuesta)

            $("#ventasCliente").empty();
            $("#ventasCliente").append(
                '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + respuesta["fecha"] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + respuesta["proyecto"] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + respuesta["total_co2cero"] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + respuesta["valor_total"] + '</td>'

            )



        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenido Camilo, puedes utilizar la función `$.each` para recorrer el arreglo.

Ejemplo:

```
$.each(resultado, function(index, value) {
    $("#ventasCliente").append(
                '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + value["fecha"] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value["proyecto"] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value["total_co2cero"] + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + value["valor_total"] + '</td>'

            )
});
```